# Forçar usuário a selecionar um item em input type datalist

Tags: php, html5

Boa noite galera, tenho o seguinte código em um sistema de hotel que estou montando:

```
<?php 
    include "Hospede.php";
    $newHospede = new Hospede();
    $rs = $newHospede->listarNomesHospedes();
    $qtdHospedes = mysql_num_rows ($rs);
?>
<input list="hospedes" name="hospede" id="hospede" required>
<datalist id="hospedes">
    <?php
        for ($cont = 0; $cont < $qtdHospedes; $cont++){
            $nome = mysql_result ($rs, $cont, "nome");
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $nome; ?>">
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</datalist>
```

O campo hóspedes possui uma lista com os nomes dos hóspedes que a consulta no banco de dados retornou, porém estou tendo um problema: devido ao fato de o campo do tipo datalist permitir ao usuário digitar para buscar um item da lista, é possível o usuário digitar qualquer coisa e submeter o formulário, já que o atributo "required" do HTML deixa passar só pelo fato de o usuário ter digitado alguma coisa dentro do campo. 
Preciso encontrar uma forma de obrigar o usuário a selecionar um item da lista. Se puderem ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: consegui fazer o que vc pediu

Comment: "a forma de colocar nesse vetor palavrasAceitas todos os nomes que a consulta no banco de dados retornou".  Editei a resposta, tá no final em Bonus.

Comment: Vlw mesmo cara, amanhã irei testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script:**

> a variável  palavrasAceitas deverá conter exatamente os valores dos options do datalist.

```js
var palavrasAceitas = ["Samba", "Blues", "Jazz", "MPB", "Rock", "Clássico", "bossanova", "Pop"],
regex = new RegExp('\\b' + palavrasAceitas.join("\\b|\\b") + '\\b', 'i');

 $(function () {
      $("input").on("change", function () {
      var valid = regex.test(this.value);
         if (valid==false){
             alert ("Termo não existente na lista");
         }
       });
  });

  function vazio() {
     var x;
     x = document.getElementById("estilo").value;
     if ((x == "")||(x == null)) {
        alert("Selecione uma opção");
        return false;
     };
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Música</legend>
    <label for="estilo"> Qual o seu estilo musical ?</label>
    <input id="estilo" name="estilo" type="text" list="listaestilos"/>
        <datalist id="listaestilos"><br/>Escolha entre estes:
            <option value="samba">Samba</option>
            <option value="blues">Blues</option>
            <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
            <option value="mpb">MPB</option>
            <option value="rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="clássico">Clássico</option>
            <option value="bossanova">Bossanova</option>
            <option value="pop">Pop</option>
        </datalist>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" onClick="return vazio()">
   </form>
```

> **BONUS** para sanar o problema descrito no comentário.
>
> Criação da variável palavrasAceitas dinamicamente para uso no script:

```
<?php 
  include "Hospede.php";
  $newHospede = new Hospede();
  $rs = $newHospede->listarNomesHospedes();
  $qtdHospedes = mysql_num_rows ($rs);
?>
 <input list="hospedes" name="hospede" id="hospede" required>
 <datalist id="hospedes">
 <?php
    for ($cont = 0; $cont < $qtdHospedes; $cont++){
        $nome = mysql_result ($rs, $cont, "nome");
        $palavrasAceitas=$palavrasAceitas.chr(34).$nome.Chr(34).",";
 ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $nome; ?>">
 <?php
    }
    $palavrasAceitas = substr($palavrasAceitas,0,-1);
    $palavrasAceitas=("var palavrasAceitas = [".$palavrasAceitas."],\nregex = new RegExp('\\\\b' + palavrasAceitas.join(".Chr(34)."\\\\b|\\\\b".Chr(34).") + '\\\\b', 'i');");
 ?>
 </datalist>

 <script language="javascript">

 <?php echo $palavrasAceitas ?>

   $(function () {
      $("input").on("change", function () {
         var valid = regex.test(this.value);
         if (valid==false){
            alert ("Termo não existente na lista");
         }
      });
   });

   function vazio() {
      var x;
      x = document.getElementById("estilo").value;
      if ((x == "")||(x == null)) {
          alert("Selecione uma opção");
          return false;
      };
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: O único problema agora é que teria que encontrar uma forma de colocar nesse vetor palavrasAceitas todos os nomes que a consulta no banco de dados retornou, pois o código está criando as opções do datalist dinamicamente de acordo com a quantidade de nomes retornados do banco de dados.

Comment: uauauau, faça outra pergunta ou edite esta que a gente dá um jeito